# Problems linking during compile of apue related code

Tags: c, ld

I am trying to compile code related to the book "Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment"

When I try to compile a test file like so:

```
$ gcc -L ../lib/ -l apue foo.c
```

I get:

```
/tmp/cccXkUae.o: In function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `err_sys'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, it seems the function is defined in the lib...

```
$ grep err_sys ../lib/libapue.a 
Binary file ../lib/libapue.a matches
```

Ultimately, this does compile with no errors:

```
$ gcc foo.c ../lib/error.c
```

Just trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: On linker command lines, always put **libraries after object files** — always!

Comment: Thanks for helping out a noob, @JonathanLeffler; you are of course correct. Compiles just fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code available 
at http://www.apuebook.com/src.3e.tar.gz gets you (after building) a header named `apue.h` in `include/` and a static lib named `libapue.a` in `lib`. So to compile and link against libapue, you need:

```
gcc -I $apue_root/include -L $apue_root/lib your_file.c -lapue
```

Comment: Thanks @PSkocik. I had already compiled the static lib... I should have mentioned that. The problem I was having was related to the position of `-lapue` being behind my source file on the command line; your answer clearly demonstrates the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linking with a static library (e.g. a `*.a` file on linux) then you can do compile your program like this:

```
gcc foo.c ../lib/libapue.a
```

If you want to link it with a dynamic (shared) library (e.g. a `*.a` file on linux) then you can use the command command that you suggested:

```
gcc -L../lib/ foo.c -lapue
```

Comment: It is better to get into the habit that always works — *libraries after object (or source) files*.  On some systems, specifying a shared library before the object files does _not_ work; the library satisfies no undefined symbols at the time, so it isn't looked at later after the object files have been scanned.